# Access Azure Storage Configuration Setting from class library

Tags: string, class, azure, connection, storage

I have a Azure project which uses the Azure Storage. The connection string for the Azure Storage is saved in the Configuration Settings for the Azure Project.

Now I have created a class library. I want to be able to load the connection string in the class library. What is the best way of doing this?

For example, do I put the connection string in the app.config for the class library? If so, will the Azure project override this automatically when I run the solution?

Comment: Will this class library project be used by your Azure project?

Comment: In any case, the best way is to use Dependency Injection and Inject your connection string! You don't want a dependency of some magic, hidden somewhere string, in your isolated classlibrary. Even if this class library is working directly with Azure and directly reference Azure assemblies. The best way is to have the storage connection string as Constructor parameter, or other type of Dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager`. The `GetSetting` method attempts to pull the setting from the Cloud configuration, but if the role isn't available (for instance because you're in a unit test), it reads from the `<AppSettings>` element inside your app.config or web.config file.

Here's the basic syntax:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;

...

var settingValue = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("SettingKey");
```

MSDN[1] says the syntax is deprecated with the release of Storage 3.0, but the class and method aren't attributed as such, so the documentation may just have a bit of copy pasta in it.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.aspx

Answer (score 0):

RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("") is what I was looking for.